# Python 3.5 SQLite INSERT works 1st time round but not the second?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, insert

I have a script which is reads the contents of a folder structure and inserts **information on each directory** and information on each **file** into an SQLite database (different tables).

When scanning, first it checks whether the directory has been scanned already. If not, it adds the directory information (path and lastmodified data) and proceeds to scan the contents. If the directory has been scanned previously and the directory hasn't been modified since the last scan, the directory is ignored and the script moves on the next directory. However if the directory has previously been scanned but the lastmodified info for this directory saved in the database shows that there *has been a modification since the last scan*, the database **file info** entries for this folder are wiped and the **directory information** is updated to show the new updated lastmodified data - after which the script enters the folder to process all the files contained in this directory.

The insert data is done as follows:

```
def executeQuery(conn, cursor, sqlstring, values):
    try:
        cursor = getCursor()
        cursor.execute(sqlstring, values)
        conn.commit()
    finally:
        cursor.close()

sqlstring = "INSERT INTO FILEDATA (fullpathandfilename, filename, filepath, scandate) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
values = (fullpathandfilename,filename,filepath, scandate)
executeQuery(conn, cursor, sqlstring, values)
```

I'm seeing some very strange behavior with this. The directory data is being written and updated correctly. The file info is being written correctly the during the first scan (i.e. when the directory is being scanned for the first time) but if the directory is re-scanned at some point because the directories lastmodified date has changed since the last recorded scan, what appears to be the same data for (fullpathandfilename,filename,filepath, scandate) are fed to the same function which doesn't fail (in a try except block the except code is not reached) - but the actual record does not reach the database.

This looks very strange to me as essentially the exact same parameters are going to the exact same function but with a different outcome.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: This sounds like maybe something is going on with the database transaction.  Perhaps it is not being committed or closed the second time?

Comment: But they both use the same function which includes conn.commit() and cursor.close(). Should I try closing the connection conn.close() after every transaction? Right now I only call that at the end of the entire process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem creating a single connection and cursor object in the module containing db related code and reducing the number of connection/cursor objects to one. Previously they were created in two different modules (rookie mistake I know).

It ended up looking like this:

```
'''
db.py
'''

conn =  sqlite3.connect(databaseName)
cursor = conn.cursor()


def executeQuery(sqlstring, values):
    try:
        cursor.execute(sqlstring, values)
        conn.commit()
    finally:
        cursor.close()


'''
anotherModule.py
'''

    sqlstring = "INSERT INTO FILEDATA (fullpathandfilename, filename, filepath, scandate) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
    values = (fullpathandfilename,filename,filepath, scandate)
    executeQuery(sqlstring, values)
```